# Will exporting data from SQL Server to Excel delete data from original database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, export

I want to export my data from a SQL Server database to an Excel sheet. But will the data in the original database (in SQL Server) be deleted? Or it will just make a copy of it?

Thank in advance!

Comment: It will ***not*** be deleted *unless* you specifically call a `DELETE FROM .....` statement ..... a `SELECT` just simply *selects* data - non destructively

Answer (score 1):

No, through the SQL import/export wizard it won't be deleted and I can't think of any other way it would be deleted by just exporting.